# If an Animated Object is given a task that takes longer than a minute to do, does the object stay animated longer than a minute?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, animated-objects, duration

So I am looking at the description of the 5th level spell [Animate Objects](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Animate%20Objects#content), it says that its duration is up to a minute, however it also says that, "once given an order, the creature continues to follow it until its task is complete". If the task lasts longer than a minute, does it continue to stay animated?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 22):

### An animated object is only a creature while the spell is active

The spell says (emphasis added):

> Each target animates and becomes a creature under your control **until the spell ends** or until reduced to 0 Hit Points.

As soon as the spell ends for any reason (end of duration, loss of concentration, dispelled, etc.), an object animated by the spell ceases to be a creature and reverts to being an object. At that point, any orders you have issued to the creature become irrelevant, because the creature no longer exists.